# Concatenating two char arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have two char arrays (char string1[7] and char string2[256]) which I need to print in a specific format. Both strings have a random number of entries terminated with a '\0' null byte.

- I need to print string1
- followed by a space on 9th character
- followed by string2 - which MUST begin printing from the 10th character onwards.

I have tried implementing this by copying the strings to a new array which I can print directly, however it is not working.

```
 while(string2[i]!='\0')
        {   


                if(i<9 && string1[i]!='\0')
                {
                    Printline[i]=string1[i];
                }
                else if (i>9)
                {
                    Printline[i]=string2[i];
                }
                i++;

        }

        printf("%s\n",Printline);
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Just use `printf` with multiple `%s` specifiers?

Comment: Do you need just to print it or you want to use this concatenated string later?

Comment: have tried using strcat but it only joins the string together. I need string1 to print in the first 8 spaces, and string2 to from from the 10th space onwards.

Comment: Don't need to use the concatenated string late, just need to print it in the format described above. :)

Comment: You increment `i` even if you don't assign anything to `Printline[i]`. Can that be right?

Comment: You know, it might be complicated, are you talking only that the second string should start from the 10-th symbol or from the 10-th byte? It is important, because there are charsets (like UTF-8) symbols of which might be larger than 1 byte.

Comment: You do realize that with `string1[7]` you are allocating space only for 6 char and the null terminator, do you? So you'll need a space for the 7th, 8th and 9th character or do you need only a space between the two strings?

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(void) {
    char string1[7];
    char string2[256];

    strncpy(string1, "str1", 6);
    strcpy(string2, "This is string 2.");

    printf("%-8s %s", string1, string2);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run, the code above will print out:

> ```
> str1     This is string 2.
> ```

The `%-8s` format specification says that, if the given string of characters is less than 8 characters long (not including `'\0'`), the string will be followed by whitespaces (blanks) to take up 8 rooms.
Furthermore, the 9th character is going to be a space and the rest will be filled up by `string2`.

Edit: `strncpy` function is used for `string1` to ensure that no more than 6 characters will be copied from *src* to *dest*. Keep in mind that the 7th character will be a null-terminator (`'\0'`).

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted!! It works perfectly!! Much appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe `strncpy`, at least for the first string, should be better. See what would happen with `"1234567"` instead of `"str1"`.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to that. This now makes sure the question is answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following needs to be corrected/clarified and not going to post the code, so that you would have a chance to learn and try to fix it.

```
while(string2[i]!='\0')  /* and further checks in the code, it appears that
                            the string2 has larger set of characters and
                            exceeds a count of 9 */
        {   
                if (i<9 && string1[i]!='\0') /* What happens when (i < 9)
                                                but string1[i] has already
                                                reached the '\0'? */
                {
                    Printline[i]=string1[i];
                }
                else if (i>9)
                {
                    Printline[i]=string2[i];
                }
                /* What about (i == 9)? */
                i++;
        }
        /* Not including '\0' from string2 before printing Printline
           would eventually crash the program */
        printf("%s\n",Printline);
```